# Force which module must load when a pripheral is connected

Tags: debian

I've a Debian 8.5 and I have an [Exar USB-RS232/485](https://www.exar.com/products/interface/uarts/usb-uarts). It can work with the cdc_acm driver, and also with the Exar's driver. I need to work with the Exar drivers to work on RS485 mode. When I start the computer sometimes the cdc_acm is loaded, and sometimes the Exar drivers is loaded. When the acm_cdc driver is loaded I've to execute:

```
rmmod cdc_acm
modprobe -r usbserial
modprobe usbserial
insmode <exar_module>
```

How can I select which driver must load the exar peripheral?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at how the USB device identifies itself (syslog). Look at the corresponding *udev* rules (`/lib/udev/rules.d/`) and add an exception as necessary. `udevadm` also helps. If you can't manage it with udev (which is the "proper" solution), you can also blacklist the cdc_acm kernel module (which will apply to all cdc_acm devices).

Comment: If you don't use the cdc_acm module for anything else, you could blacklist it from being loaded....